# Stored-Proc-like Transformation Trigger for succeeding Hive inserts

Tags: hive, etl

We have two tables in Hive, the first one, let's call it Table A, is where the raw data is being dumped. The data in Table B is derived from Table A after some HiveQL transformation. (I understand there are no stored procedures in Hive). When new data will be inserted on Table A, how do we automatically trigger the process of doing the same transformation and appending the result on Table B?

Comment: Is the addition to B based only on the new rows  inserted to A or does it involve older rows of A?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Let's assume that what goes to B from A is 1-1.

Comment: In that case you might want to use an additional staging table and from there to fill both A and B. Another option is to hold a watermark over A, as long as A is partitioned by the insert date/timestamp and the delta can be retrieved efficiently.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz What do you mean watermark? An identifier somewhat that this partition of A has been processed into B or not? If I go by this solution, how do we go about making this automated or triggered?

Comment: I suppose you control the insert to A. You insert to A. You retrieve the new data from A (based on your current watermark) process it and insert to B. You change the watermark.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Like a parameterized WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, again - as long it is based on the partitions, so the retrieval will be efficient